# Mysql join user and event table

Tags: mysql, events, join

I have user and evet table,

user table :

`+----+---------------+----------+
| id | name          | document |
+----±---------------±----------+
| 1  | Andrew        | 1        |
| 2  | Ricky         | 0        |
| 3  | Joe           | 0        |
| 4  | Steve         | 0        |
±----±---------------±----------±`

event table :

`+----+---------------+----------+--------+
| id | date          | iduser   | status |
+----±---------------±----------+--------+
| 1  | 2014-06-17    | 2        | 0      |
| 2  | 2014-06-20    | 1        | 0      |
| 3  | 2014-07-05    | 3        | 0      |
| 4  | 2014-07-11    | 1        | 0      |
| 5  | 2014-06-30    | 2        | 1      |
±----±---------------±----------±--------+`

User can create event and tell their status 0 (off) or 1 (on) on that date. And if user have no event, their status deemed to be not off.
And now i want to select random user with lowest document and status is not off for today (2014-06-17).

`SELECT user.name FROM user LEFT OUTER JOIN event ON user.id = event.iduser WHERE user.document =  ( SELECT MIN(user.document) FROM user) AND DATE(event.date) = DATE(NOW()) AND event.status !=0 ORDER by RAND() LIMIT 1`

it give no result. 
If i remove the status condition, it return with Ricky.
Please help me how to solve this query so the result will return just Joe or Steve.
Many thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For left joins, you cannot have conditions on the right side table (in this case `event`) in the WHERE clause, or it will turn into an inner join. You'll have to move all conditions on `event` into the ON clause;

```
SELECT user.name 
FROM user 
LEFT OUTER JOIN event 
  ON user.id = event.iduser 
  AND DATE(event.date) = DATE(NOW()) 
  AND event.status = 0 
WHERE user.document = ( 
    SELECT MIN(user.document) 
    FROM user
  ) AND event.id IS NULL
ORDER by RAND() LIMIT 1
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cadf10/1).

Comment: Great it works... But if i run query for the 2nd time or so, sometimes it will return Ricky as result while Ricky status is 0. Probably because there are two Ricky id with different date in event table. How can i solve this? Thank you..

Comment: @Zony Ah, I turned the condition the wrong way, looking for a `1` in status instead of a `0`. Updated the answer.